# Make a text file in a certain directory from another directory in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

Was wondering how the code would look like if you wanted to create a file in a certain directory from another directory in unix.

Example:

```
File to be created: pop.txt
Directory to create that in: /home/p1
Directory you are currently in and are to make it from: /home/pokemon/master/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
touch /home/p1/pop.txt
```

Simple like that

Comment: If the answer is correct mark it as so. Otherwise Stack overflow won't know if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way.
because touch only create a empty file. but this you can add the content also.

cat > /home/p1/pop.txt

vim > /home/p1/pop.txt

cat is used in the terminal. vim is a editor.

Are else you can use this way.

cat > ../../p1/pop.txt

vim ../../p1/pop.txt

.. means a back reference or previous directory.